Powering an ADC and a MCU from 12 V to 24 V
the concept is about an evaluation board that allows measuring up to 4 parallel load-cells from an ADC and process the output in an MCU:

Input voltage to the entire circuit: 12 V to 24 V with typically 24 V
ADC: TI ADS1220
MCU: STM32F103
Digital voltage: 3V3
Analog voltage: 5V low noise for load-cell excitation and AVDD of the ADC

Low noise LDO linear voltage regulators, like the ADI LT3045, seem to max out at 20 V input voltage and rails with multiple voltage regulators seem extremely complex regarding part count and design complexity.
I would be very grateful for any proposal how to manage this pragmatically. Many thanks in advance.
Edit - Expected Power-Budget:

3V3 rail: < 200 mA
5 V rail: < 100 mA


You could use a switching DC-DC converter to reduce the 12-24V input voltage to some intermediate voltage such as 9V or lower, then use a linear regulator for the low-noise 5V analog rail and either a linear regulator or another switching regulator for the 3.3V digital rail (depending on the required current and so on).
When you have multiple rails, you should pay attention to what happens if one is present and the other isn't, in all potential combinations, even transient ones, and mitigate any potential issues. Otherwise problems or failures can result.

Okay, now that we have some numbers:
To draw the entire amount with linear regulators from a 24VDC supply (please distinguish between LDO and other linear regulators) would throw away more than (24-3.3)x0.2+(24-5)x0.1= 6W. That's a fairly large heat sink and a lot of wasted energy. Do-able but ugly.
Let's try the DC-DC converter. We can try TI's Webench, which will, of course, try to sell us TI parts which may be much more expensive or less applicable than competitors, but it's a start--
If we derive the entire 300mA (plus a bit) from the 24V supply, and try for a 6V output.. that will allow an LDO for the 5V and an ordinary linear regulator for the 3.3V.

And presto, we have 8 different designs all with BOMs and suggested supplier part numbers for passive components (very important for switching converters). Here is the first one:

With a free account we can run simulations. I've done the steady-state with 350mA out. And it will produce a nicely formatted 8-page report. Efficiency is 90%+ at full load. Here is the power dissipation of all the components:

TPS54202DDCR IC Pd peaks at maximum Vin (25V) and output current at about 175mW. According to the datasheet that will result in only about 16°C temperature rise above ambient. Pretty decent. This is a 500kHz SMPS chip so it's essential to follow layout recommendations to the letter.
Now we've got that 6V rail you didn't ask for, at up to 350mA.
So we could add an inexpensive 78M33 to get the 3.3V digital rail. Or just about any other linear or LDO regulator with 3.3V out. Power dissipation will be about 0.5W so better to use a TO252 package.
And for the 5V rail, perhaps a TPS7A2050PDBVR. It will need to dissipate about 100mW, so SOT-23 is fine (about 20°C rise).
So there is one solution. Three common ICs, one inductor and about a dozen passive components (mostly capacitors, plus two resistors and an inductor), very simple indeed. For low noise the devil is in the details though.
I'm sure you can see that there are almost infinite other possibilities that will trade off parts cost and complexity vs. efficiency and noise.

Thank you very much for the answer. As I'm not a professional and doing this for a hobby, I had hoped there might be some reference design available, or some guidance of components that fulfill these requirements. I looked at so many regulators' datasheets and I'm "mildly" overwhelmed.

The regulators will have applications circuits in the data sheets, however you need to know your requirements before you can get started. Big difference between needing 1A at 3.3V vs 50mA.

I have edited the question to reflect the power budget.
